# Does the courses request in google classroom return archived courses too?

Tags: google-classroom

Once the teacher has archived a course, say at the end of the school year, will the API still return it when requesting a list of courses for that teacher?

Comment: You could try manually setting the `CourseState` to `ARCHIVED` and then request the list and check if it appears. https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses#CourseState

Answer (score 1):

Yes, archived courses are returned, but not deleted ones.

Answer (score 0):

Yes archived course returned by google classroom api with state "ARCHIVED" in json.